# Error while compiling regex function, why am I getting this issue?

Tags: regex, raku

My RAKU Code:

```
sub comments {
    if ($DEBUG) { say "<filtering comments>\n"; }
    my @filteredtitles = ();

    # This loops through each track
    for @tracks -> $title {

        ##########################
        # LAB 1 TASK 2           #
        ##########################
        ## Add regex substitutions to remove superflous comments and all that follows them
        ## Assign to $_ with smartmatcher (~~)
        ##########################
        $_ = $title;

        if ($_) ~~ s:g:mrx/ .*<?[\(^.*]> / {

        # Repeat for the other symbols

        ########################## End Task 2

        # Add the edited $title to the new array of titles
            @filteredtitles.push: $_;
        }
    }
        # Updates @tracks
        return @filteredtitles;
}
```

Result when compiling:
[Error Compiling! Placeholder variable '@_' may not be used here because the surrounding block doesn't take a signature.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpK75.png)

Is there something obvious that I am missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain your regex adverbs on the right side of the `~~` smartmatch operator? I see `:r` might stand for ratcheting, but I don't think Raku has a `:x`  equivalent of Perl5's `/x`, since the 'disregard whitespace' switch is now Raku's default. Maybe something like `m:r:g` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in contrast with @raiph's answer, here's what I have:

```
my @tracks = <Foo Ba(r B^az>.map: { S:g / <[\(^]> // };
```

Just that. Nothing else. Let's dissect it, from the inside out:

This part: `/ <[\(^]> /` is a regular expression that will match one character, as long as it is an open parenthesis (represented by the `\(`) or a caret (`^`). When they go inside the angle brackets/square brackets combo, it means that is an [Enumerated character class](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Enumerated_character_classes_and_ranges).

Then, the: `S` introduces the [non-destructive substitution](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#S///_non-destructive_substitution), i.e., a quoting construct that will make regex-based substitutions over the topic variable `$_` but will not modify it, just return its value with the modifications requested. In the code above, `S:g` brings the adverb `:g` or `:global` (see the [global adverb](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Global) in the adverbs section of the documentation) to play, meaning (in the case of the substitution) *"please make as many as possible of this substitution"* and the final `/` marks the end of the substitution text, and as it is adjacent to the second `/`, that means that

```
S:g / <[\(^]> //
```

means *"please return the contents of `$_`, but modified in such a way that all its characters matching the regex `<[\(^]>` are deleted (substituted for the empty string)"*

At this point, I should emphasize that regular expressions in Raku are ***really*** powerful, and that reading the entire page (and probably the [best practices and gotchas](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes-best-practices) page too) is a good idea.

Next, the: `.map` method, [documented here](https://docs.raku.org/routine/map#(List)_routine_map), will be applied to any `Iterable` (`List`, `Array` and all their alikes) and will return a sequence based on each element of the `Iterable`, altered by a `Code` passed to it. So, something like:

```
@x.map({ S:g / foo /bar/ })
```

essencially means *"please return a `Seq`uence of every item on `@x`, modified by substituting any appearance of the substring `foo` for `bar`"* (nothing will be altered on `@x`). [A nice place to start to learn about sequences and iterables would be here](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq).

Finally, my one-liner

```
my @tracks = <Foo Ba(r B^az>.map: { S:g / <[\(^]> // };
```

can be translated as:

I have a `List` with three string elements

```
Foo
Ba(r
B^az
```

(This would be a placeholder for your "list of titles"). Take that list and generate a second one, that contains every element on it, but with all instances of the chars "open parenthesis" and "caret" removed.

Ah, and store the result in the variable `@tracks` (that has `my` scope)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
my @tracks = <Foo Ba(r B^az>;

sub comments {

    my @filteredtitles;

    for @tracks -> $_ is copy {

        s:g / <[\(^]> //;

        @filteredtitles.push: $_;
    }

    return @filteredtitles;
}
```

The `is copy` ensures the variable set up by the `for` loop is mutable.

The `s:g/...//;` is all that's needed to strip the unwanted characters.

---

One thing no one can help you with is the error you reported. I currently think you just got confused.

Here's an example of code that generates that error:

```
do { @_ }
```

But there is no way the code you've shared could generate that error because it requires that there is an `@_` variable in your code, and there isn't one.

---

One way I can help in relation to *future* problems you may report on StackOverflow is to encourage you to read and apply the guidance in [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

While your code did not generate the error you reported, it will perhaps help you if you know about some of the *other* compile time and run time errors there were in the code you shared.

Compile-time errors:

- You wrote `s:g:mrx`. That's invalid: `Adverb mrx not allowed on substitution`.
- You missed out the third slash of the `s///`. That causes mayhem (see below).

There were several run-time errors, once I got past the compile-time errors. I'll discuss just one, the regex:

- `.*<?[...]>` will *match* any sub-string with a final character that's one of the ones listed in the `[...]`, and will then *capture* that sub-string except *without the final character*. In the context of an `s:g/...//` substitution this will strip ordinary characters (captured by the `.*`) but leave the special characters.

  This makes no sense.

  So I dropped the `.*`, and also the `?` from the special character pattern, changing it from `<?[...]>` (which just tries to *match* against the character, but does **not** *capture* it if it succeeds) to just `<[...]>` (which *also* tries to *match* against the character, but, if it succeeds, **does** *capture* it as well).

---

A final comment is about an error you made that may well have seriously confused you.

In a nutshell, the `s///` construct **must** have **three** slashes.

In your question you had code of the form `s/.../` (or `s:g/.../` etc), without the final slash. If you try to compile such code the parser gets utterly confused because it will think you're just writing a long replacement string.

For example, if you wrote this code:

```
if s/foo/ { say 'foo' }
if m/bar/ { say 'bar' }
```

it'd be as if you'd written:

```
if s/foo/ { say 'foo' }\nif m/...
```

which in turn would mean you'd get the compile-time error:

```
Missing block
------> if m/⏏bar/ { ... }
    expecting any of:
        block or pointy block
        ...
```

because Raku(do) would have interpreted the part between the second and third `/`s as the replacement double quoted string of what it interpreted as an `s/.../.../` construct, leading it to barf when it encountered `bar`.

So, to recap, the `s///` construct requires **three** slashes, not *two*.

(I'm ignoring syntactic variants of the construct such as, say, `s [...] = '...'`.)

Comment: just `@tracks.map: { S:g / <[\(^]> // }` seems to do the trick ;-)

Comment: @Massa Nice one liner. :) Would you be willing to write that up as an answer? Just the `my @tracks` line plus your one liner? Maybe with some brief explanation / links to the doc? I think it would make a nice contrast with my long answer, and would get most of the upvotes, and would hopefully get accepted if @Homerian ever returns to SO, and that those would all be good things. :)

Comment: Will do, in a couple of minutes!